# Ternary conditional operator in interpolated strings in F#

Tags: f#, string-interpolation

Is it possible to use the ternary conditional operator in an interpolated string?
Something like:

```ml
printfn $"""This is a string{($", and here's the inner string: {innerString}!" if boolFlag  else "!")}\n"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any valid F# expression when using string interpolation, including the `if` expression. Just use the standard F# way of writing it `if <boo> then <e1> else <e2>`:

```
let boolFlag = true
let innerString = "Yo"

printfn $"""This is a string{
  if boolFlag then $", and here's the inner string: {innerString}!" 
  else "!"}\n"""
```

Comment: thanks - it was totally a typo, I could have figure it out myself, sorry about that. (btw the result is not particularly readable, I don't think I'll use it..)